# Associate a URI with a program

Tags: windows-7

How can I manually associate a custom uri to a program?

What I'd like to do in this case is map `rdp://` to `mstsc`. I'm guessing I'd also have to do some work to tell it how to parse the uri.

For example....

```
rdp://domain\myusername@mycomputer:23498
```

Would open up an rdp connection to `mycomputer` on port `23498` with username `domain\myusername`. Actually looking at the documentation for `mstsc` it looks like I can't specify a user name so I would need to discard it.

Comment: What browser do you need to map URI in?

Comment: would prefer in the shell... so i could type the uri in start bar and it would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The problem is that Internet Explorer (or any other useragent) can only pass the full URI to foreign application and not divides it by any parts (obviously). So you probably need to create some handler for it. If it would be some POSIX system I'd `sed | xargs` it, but I don't know if there are any features in MS batch files that allow similar text parsing.

Comment: awesome, in the comments of the link there is a program http://www.codeplex.com/CustomURL does exactly what I need, parses the uri and can access the parts you need even has an example for mstsc.exe usage